# GSON can be an array of string or an array of object

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to create a GSON class but not sure how to handle this case.

According to the API specifications `options` can be a list values: ["one", "two"]
OR

can be a list of {"value": "Label"} pairs to provide labels for values

```
{
...
  "options": ["one", "two", "three"],
}
```

OR

```
{
...
  "options": [{"light": "Solarized light"}, {"dark": "Solarized dark"}],
}
```

Comment: JSON communication is based on a mutual agreement between the client & the server (a contract). This means that you need to know what structure you receive before-hand. The type of `options` shouldn't change in a proper API, hence why you're facing this issue

Answer (score 2):

You can map this field to `Map<String, String>`:

```
class Pojo {

    @JsonAdapter(OptionsJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Map<String, String> options;

    // getters, setters, toString, other properties
}
```

List of primitives means that you have only values (without labels). In case of list of `JSON Object`s you have values with labels. Now, you need to implement custom deserialiser for given property:

```
class OptionsJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Map<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray();
            array.forEach(item -> {
                if (item.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                    map.put(item.getAsString(), null);
                } else if (item.isJsonObject()) {
                    item.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                        map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getAsString());
                    });
                }
            });

            return map;
        }

        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        Pojo pojo = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Pojo.class);
        System.out.println(pojo);
    }
}
```

For `JSON object`s:

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "light": "Solarized light"
    },
    {
      "dark": "Solarized dark"
    }
  ]
}
```

prints:

```
Pojo{options={light=Solarized light, dark=Solarized dark}}
```

For list of primitives:

```
{
  "options": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ]
}
```

Prints:

```
Pojo{options={one=null, two=null, three=null}}
```