# array of objects with java json

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I've been trying to read an array of object json using java.

here's my json file:

```
 {
    "title": "The Social network",
    "summary": "On a fall night in 2003,Havard undergrad and \n programming genius Mark Zuckerberg sits down at his \n computer and heatedly begins working on a new idea.(...)",
    "year": 2010,
    "director": {
        "last_name": "fincher",
        "first_name": "David"
    },
    "actors": [{
            "first_name": "Jesse",
            "last_name": "Eisenberg"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Roney",
            "last_name": "Mara"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've made two classes

```
public class film {
private String title;
private String summary;
private int year;
private personne director;
private personne[] actors;
```

and the personne class, both with getters and setters and simple tostring method

and here my main in which I try to read

```
public class FilmJsonReader {

    public static final String JSON_FILE="C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\JSON project\\FILM.txt";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(JSON_FILE);
        
        //create JsonReader object
        JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(fis);
        
        //get JsonObject from JsonReader
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
        
        //we can close IO resource and JsonReader now
        jsonReader.close();
        fis.close();
        
        //Retrieve data from JsonObject and create Employee bean
        film Film = new film();
        
        Film.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
        Film.setSummary(jsonObject.getString("summary"));
        Film.setYear(jsonObject.getInt("year"));
        
        //reading inner object from json object
                JsonObject innerJsonObject = jsonObject.getJsonObject("address");
                personne director = new personne();
                director.setFirst_name(innerJsonObject.getString("first_name"));
                director.setLast_name(innerJsonObject.getString("last_name"));
                Film.setDirector(director);
        
                //reading arrays from json
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJsonArray("actors");
        personne[] actors = new personne[jsonArray.size()];
        personne p = new personne();
        int i = 0;
        for(JsonValue value : jsonArray){
            actors[i++]=p.toString(value.toString());
        }
        Film.setActors(actors);
        
        //print employee bean information
        System.out.println(Film);
        
    }

}
```

but here's the output, I am having problems reading the object inside of the array

```
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
title=The Social network<br />
summary=On a fall night in 2003,Havard undergrad and (...)<br />
year=2010<br />
director=fincher, David<br />
 **actors= null null  **<br />
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: `actors` is a `personne[]`, but you're assigning the `toString()` output of an empty `personne` to each location?  I can't figure out how this even compiles.

Comment: me either , i am runnig out time, what you suggest as a solution !!

Comment: Reading some JSON is a general purpose task well performed by some libraries. In the last project I've used <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_(API)>

Comment: Try to use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate model for given `JSON` payload and after that [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to deserialise it. Related questions: [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo), [GSON can be an array of string or an array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011652/gson-can-be-an-array-of-string-or-an-array-of-object).

Comment: I strongly recommend you to leverage JSON libraries for deserialization such as `Jackson`, `Gson` or `org.json` which are the most popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you need to create a new personne object for each actor in the JSON array. You can do this exactly the same way that you created the director and then instead of `Film.setDirector(director);` you can call: `actors[i++]=actor` where `actor` is the personne you just made. Hope this helps